# retrieve error code from a command launched within a bash script

Tags: bash, error-handling

Ok I'm kind of new to bash scripting [the advanced stuff] and I need a little help. I don't even know exactly how to phrase this so I'll just explain what I am doing and what I need to know about it.
in my script I run a ./configure and I need to be able to catch if there was an error in the configure and react accordingly within the bash script.

the code is:

```
function dobuild {
echo -e "\e[1;35;40mExecuting Bootstrap and Configure\e[0m"
cd /devel/xbmc
if [ $Debug = "1" ];
then
#either outputs to screen or nulls output
./bootstrap >/dev/null
/usr/bin/auto-apt run ./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-gl --enable-vdpau --enable-crystalhd --enable-rtmp --enable-libbluray  >/dev/null
else
./bootstrap
/usr/bin/auto-apt run ./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-gl --enable-vdpau --enable-crystalhd --enable-rtmp --enable-libbluray
fi
}
```

and say the configure returns an error 1 or 2 how do I trap that and act on it?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the execution of a command, the returned value is stored in the shell variable $?. So you would have to match that with the return values of success and failure

```
if [ $? == 1 ]
then
    #do something
else
    #do something else
fi
```

Comment: I just found that exact string googling. so if I did a ./configure and it run and ended with an error of 1 then that would allow me to do something right? and I could elif [ $1 == 2 ] if it had an error of 2?

Comment: Right.. except for the fact that in your script, the return value would be that returned by `/usr/bin/auto-apt`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I am not exactly sure what you mean by that.

Comment: The command that you actually run from your script is not `./configure`, it is actually `/usr/bin/auto-apt`, to which `./configure` is passed as an argument. So it is `/usr/bin/auto-apt` that is in fact running `./configure`. The return value that you get in your shell in `$?` is the value returned by `/usr/bin/auto-apt`. I hope I have clarified it?

Comment: yah I kind of figured that but I was just using ./configure as an example :) 
`if [ "$?" == "0" ];
then
echo "no errors."
elif [ "$?" == "1" ]
then
echo "there was an error. Report it and exit"
end_run
elif [ "$?" == "2" ]
then
echo "there was an error. Report it and exit"
end_run
fi` seems to work great :)

Comment: @user1567394;  Warning Will Robinson!  It only seems to work, that code will not detect an error 2.  See my post about the dangers.  (and why are you doing a textual comparison for a numeric value?)

Answer (score 3):

After the execution of every shell command it's return value, a number between 0 and 255, is available in the shell variable `?`.  You can get the value of this variable by prefixing it with the `$` operator.

You have to be a little careful with `?`, because it is reset by every command, **even a test**.  For example:

```
some_command
if (( $? != 0 ))
then
   echo "Error detected! $?" >&2
fi
```

Gives: `Error detected! 0` because `?` was reset by the test condition.  It is probably best to store `?` in another variable if you are going to use it later, *which includes doing more than one test on it*.

To do a numeric test in bash use the `(( ... ))` numeric test construct:

```
some_command
result=$?
if (( $result == 0 ))
then
   echo "it worked!"
elif (( $result == 1 ))
then
    echo "Error 1 detected!" >&2
elif (( $result == 2 ))
then
    echo "Error 2 detected!" >&2
else
    echo "Some other error was detected: $result" >&2
fi
```

Alternatively use a `case` statement.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers about $? are great (though be careful about assuming values other than 0 and not-0 - different commands. or different versions of the same command may fail with different values), but if you just need to act on success or failure immediately, you can simplify things:

```
if command ; then
    # success code here
else
    # failure code here
fi
```

Or if you only want to act on failure, here's a hack for older shells (the colon is a null command but it satisfies the then clause):

```
if command ; then : 
else
    # failure code here
fi
```

But in modern shells like bash this is better:

```
if ! command ; then   # use the ! (not) operator 
    # failure code here
fi
```

And, if you only need to do simple things, you can use the "short circuit" operators:

```
   command1 && command2_if_command1_succeeds
   command1 || command2_if_command1_fails
```

Those only work for single commands, stringing more && and || on them doesn't do what you might think in most cases so most people avoid that. However, you can do multiple commands if you group them:

```
   command1 && { command2; command3; command4; }
```

That can get hard to read so it's best to keep it simple if you use it all:

```
   command1 || { echo "Error, command1 failed!" >&2; exit 1; }
```